# Yolov4 Weights into ONNX format

Tags: onnx, darknet, yolov4

How can I convert Yolov4 Custom object-trained weights(best weights) into an ONNX format before starting the inferencing part with TensorRT?

After training my image(custom dataset) in Yolov4 using Darknet, I want to convert my Trained weights(Best weights) into ONNNX file in order to use the ONNX file for inferencing with TensorRT.

Comment: You can convert cfg+weight file direct to the TensorRT: https://github.com/enazoe/yolo-tensorrt

Comment: Hello@Nuzhny,                                                                                                                 Thank you for your reply.I will check with the Github account provided by you to change my weights to TensorRT.